# Understanding of css textarea offsets

Tags: html, css, textarea, typography

I made a simple example of textarea on jsfiddle with font-size and line-height.

[JSFiddle textarea](http://jsfiddle.net/shkboca2/)

```
textarea {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 4;
    height: 260px;
}

<textarea>
A
A
A
</textarea>
```

[image: Offsets between lines]
[image: Small caret]
[image: Big caret]

1) How does browser calculate the AREA_1 height and the AREA_2 height? Why are they different?

2) How does browser calculate the caret size in the textarea? Why does the caret at the first line is much smaller that at the second line?

Comment: I checked this in Firefox and Safari - absolutely the same behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it is a bug on Chromium: [Cursor line-height bug on inputs](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426802)

> CSS uses what is known as half-leading to render lines of text. This
>   is determ­ined by work­ing out the dif­fer­ence between the
>   line-height and the font-size, divid­ing by 2, and then pla­cing the
>   cal­cu­lated amount of space above and below each line of text. So if
>   you have a font-size of 16px and an effect­ive line-height of 24px,
>   the half-leading would be 4px.

By [Joshua Hibbert](http://joshnh.com/2012/10/12/how-does-line-height-actually-work/).

Comment: Is there anything way to prevent top offset from first line of the text?

Comment: set a small value to the `line-height`, same or slightly larger than the font size.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think the browser uses equal heights above and below one line. Like so:

```
-----

A

-----

A

-----
```

2) In my browser (Firefox) the caret is always the same size.

Comment: I checked this in Firefox and Safari - absolutely the same behavior. And as I showed in original post - these heights are not equal.